# How can I add a cronjob in yocto build?

Tags: linux, yocto, yocto-recipe

I want to add a cronjob in yocto while baking the receipe, is there any way to do that?

The cronjob will look something like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/myScript >>/var/log/cronrun 2>&1
```

Comment: `git grep ".*install.*cron"` in `meta-openembedded` for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way, you can use the cronie recipe to achieve that:
https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/recipes-extended/cronie/cronie_1.5.7.bb

If you take a closer look at that recipe, it already contains a crontab that runs scripts hourly,daily,weekly,etc.

All you need to do is have your recipe install a file containing your cronjob in the proper directory:
/etc/cron.hourly
/etc/cron.daily

```
# For example
SRC_URI = "file://my-cronjob"

do_install(){
  install -d ${D}/${sysconfdir}/cron.hourly
  install -m 755 ${WORKDIR}/my-cronjob ${D}/${sysconfdir}/cron.hourly/my-cronjob
}
FILES:${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/cron.hourly/my-cronjob"
```