# Can not install cronjob file in yocto build, run.do_install error

Tags: linux, cron, yocto

I am trying to add a file my-cronjob.cron to /etc/cron.d inside my new meta-layer

The file tree is the following:

```
meta-customLayer
└── recipes-myCustomLayer
    └── myCustomLayer
        ├── files
        │   └── my-cronjob.cron
        └── myCustomLayer.bb
```

my CustomLayer.bb :

```
PR = "r0"
PACKAGES = "${PN} ${PN}-dev ${PN}-dbg ${PN}-staticdev"

RDEPENDS_${PN}-staticdev = ""
RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev = ""
RDEPENDS_${PN}-dbg = ""
RDEPENDS_${PN} = ""

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/${sysconfdir}/cron.d
    install -m 755  "${THISDIR}/files/testApp-cronjob.cron" ${sysconfdir}/cron.d/

}

FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/cron.d/testApp-cronjob"
```

And when i try to build the imahge i get the following error:

```
ERROR: myCustomLayer-1.0-r0 do_install: Execution of '/***/imx-yocto/build-core-image-base/tmp/work/cortexa35-poky-linux/myCustomLayer/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_install.16326' failed with exit code 1:
install: cannot create regular file '/etc/cron.d/testApp-cronjob.cron': Permission denied
```

Any idea why I get this error? Any way to add this cronjob to yocto?

Comment: Please mark as accepted the answer on the original question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847881/how-can-i-add-a-cronjob-in-yocto-build/70858958#70858958
, you may follow up on that same thread instead of asking additional questions

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the destination suffix:

```
install -m 755  "${THISDIR}/files/testApp-cronjob.cron" ${D}${sysconfdir}/cron.d/
```